# Handled 'Uncaught Exception' is still somehow crashing the app

Tags: node.js, uncaught-exception, winston

Looking for ideas on how to debug an app that is crashing randomly without being caught by:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){});
```

I've also had no luck trying Winston (the log file remains empty) to catch whatever is causing the app to crash:

```
winston.handleExceptions(new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'exceptions.log' }))
```

What kind of program faults can even get past these?

Comment: uncaughtException are real bad, and can mess with a lot more than what you expect, you should try to locate it instead of trying to go around it.

Comment: That's my main problem - I really don't know what is causing it.

Comment: You sure there isn't an external reason (like Linux's OOM killer) that's killing your app?

Comment: I've considered external causes but can't think of any that would do this on a Windows 7 Ultimate deployment.  Also, I have a similar node app running in a separate process which has never crashed without an entry in my uncaughtException log.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty but the following was enough to do the job for me:

```
setInterval(function(){winston.logger.info(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS')+' ' + process.memoryUsage().rss)}, dt_timer);
```

Also, one answer to the question regarding what type of program fault can crash a node app that is handling 'uncaughtException' - **Memory Leaks!**

Cheers.